# Binary Tree Bin Packing Algorithm in C

Tags: javascript, c, algorithm

## What I'm trying to do:

I saw [this](https://codeincomplete.com/posts/bin-packing/) Algorithm, it's made with javascript and I'm trying to do  `Packing Blocks into a Fixed Rectangle` in C.
In my code, shown below, I read data from a `.txt`. This part have no problem, I'm just making a array of pointers to `struct Blocks` and after I sort it.
After that I'm doing exactly like the code in the article, same logic, and that is where the errors are happening.

### My Code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

typedef struct Block
{
    struct Node* fit;
    int width;
    int height;
    int x;
    int y;
    int id;
} Block;

typedef struct Node {
    struct Node* down;
    struct Node* right;
    int used;   
    int width;
    int height;
    int x;
    int y;
} Node;

Node *findNode(Node *root, int w, int h);
Node *splitNode(Node **root, int w, int h);

int main()
{
    FILE *file;
    char line[80];
    Block **blocks; 
    int totalBoards, boardWidth, boardHeight, totalBlocks;
    int i = 1, j;

    Node *root = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    root->x = 0;
    root->y = 0;
    root->used = 0;
    root->id = 0;

    fopen_s(&file, "blocks.txt", "r");

    // Reading the file
    while (fgets(line, 80, file)) {
        if (i == 1) {
            sscanf_s(line, "%d\n", &totalBoards);
        } else if (i == 2) {
            sscanf_s(line, "%d\n", &boardWidth);
            root->width = boardWidth;
        } else if (i == 3) {
            sscanf_s(line, "%d\n", &boardHeight);
            root->height = boardHeight;
        } else if (i == 4) {
            sscanf_s(line, "%d\n", &totalBlocks);
            blocks = malloc(totalBlocks * sizeof(Block *));

        } else {            
            int w, h;
            blocks[i - 5] = malloc(sizeof(Block));
            sscanf_s(line, "%d %d", &w, &h);
            blocks[i - 5]->width = w;
            blocks[i - 5]->height = h;
            blocks[i - 5]->id = i - 5;
        }

        i++;
    }

    //Bubble sort
    for (i = 0; i < totalBlocks; i++) {

        for (j = 0; j < totalBlocks - i - 1; j++)

            if (blocks[j]->height < blocks[j + 1]->height) {                
                Block *b = blocks[j];
                blocks[j] = blocks[j + 1];
                blocks[j + 1] = b;
            }
    }

    // THE IMPORTANT PART
    // The logic used by the algorithm
    // fit function
    for (i = 0; i < totalBlocks; i++) {
        Block *block = blocks[i];   
        Node *node;
        if (node = findNode(root, block->width, block->height)) {
            block->fit = splitNode(&node, block->width, block->height);
        }
    }

    //Print the blocks
    for (i = 0; i < totalBlocks; i++) {
        Block *block = blocks[i];
        if (block->fit) {           
            printf("x %d y %d\n", blocks[i]->fit->x, blocks[i]->fit->y);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

Node *findNode(Node *root, int w, int h) {
    printf("%d", root->id);
    if (root->used == 1) {
        //Error Here
        return findNode(root->down, w, h) || findNode(root->right, w, h);
    }
    else if ((w <= root->width) && (h <= root->height)) {
        return root;
    }
    else {
        return NULL;
    }
}

Node *splitNode(Node **root, int w, int h) {

    (*root)->used = 1;
    (*root)->down = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    (*root)->down->right = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    (*root)->down->down = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    (*root)->down->x = (*root)->x;
    (*root)->down->y = (*root)->y + h;
    (*root)->down->width = (*root)->width;
    (*root)->down->height = (*root)->height - h;
    (*root)->down->used = 0;
    (*root)->down->id = idCount;
    idCount++;


    (*root)->right = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    (*root)->right->right = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    (*root)->right->down = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    (*root)->right->x = (*root)->x + w;
    (*root)->right->y = (*root)->y;
    (*root)->right->width = (*root)->width - w;
    (*root)->right->height = (*root)->height;
    (*root)->right->used = 0;
    (*root)->right->id = idCount;
    idCount++;

    return *root;
}
```

## The Error:

In this part, the returned `Node` from `findNode` is going wrong

```
if (node = findNode(root, block->width, block->height)) {
    block->fit = splitNode(&node, block->width, block->height);
}
```

when it's returned by

```
return findNode(root->down, w, h) || findNode(root->right, w, h);
```

because when I use the varible `node` in `splitNode`

```
block->fit = splitNode(&node, block->width, block->height);
```

all atributes of the `node` are NULL and it's causing a error.

## The Problem:

In the code of this [article](https://codeincomplete.com/posts/bin-packing/), it's returned the following

```
return this.findNode(root.right, w, h) || this.findNode(root.down, w, h);
```

and in C I'm returning

```
return findNode(root->right, w, h) || findNode(root->down, w, h);
```

And I thinks the error is here.

## Solutions?

I think that `return ___ || ___` is not doing the same for both languages. So I have two questions:

1. `return ___ || ___` is doing the same ins both languages? If not, what is the difference and what is the C code equivalent for that code in javascript?
2. What is wrong with my code? Why is that error happening and not returning the correct node like in the javascript code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in your assumption that `||` has different semantics in JavaScript and C.

In JavaScript, `a || b` returns `a` if `a` is "truthy" and `b` if `a` is `falsy`.

Meanwhile in C, `a || b` is a boolean expression. It will always return `true` or `false` instead of the original expressions.

For example, `5 || 0`  is `5` in JavaScript but `1` in C.

Replacing `return findNode(root->right, w, h) || findNode(root->down, w, h);` with

```
Node *answer = findNode(root->right, w, h);
if (answer) return answer;
else return findNode(root->down, w, h);
```

should work.

Comment: @Vencovsky That's probably because findNode is mutating the structure. I will update the answer.

Comment: @Vencovsky On another look, the function isn't mutating anything so my original implementation should have been fine. But whether you pick right or down first would make a difference and your choice for what goes on the left is inconsistent among various parts of the question

Comment: Sorry I said it was wrong,  your code was doing the same thing as the javascript. I just realized that how i was sorting the Blocks was making a huge diference, and that's why i tought it was wrong. But your answer it 100% correct, thanks!