# Binary Tree Bin Packing 2D Algorithm in C

Tags: javascript, c, algorithm

## Background:

I'm trying to replicate [this](https://codeincomplete.com/posts/bin-packing/) Algorithm in C, the `Packing Blocks into a Fixed Rectangle` part and I already make a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53536607/binary-tree-bin-packing-algorithm-in-c) about it, the solution to that question was correct, but it didn't fixed the overall problem. I have found specific input that is causing a  "error" and to show that, I set the values statically in the code just to make it easier for testing.

## My C Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define COUNT 10

typedef struct Block
{
    struct Node* fit;
    int width;
    int height;
    int x;
    int y;
    int id;

} Block;

typedef struct Node 
{
    struct Node* parent;
    struct Node* down;
    struct Node* right;
    int used;   
    int width;
    int height;
    int x;
    int y;

} Node;

Node *findNode(Node *root, int w, int h);
Node *splitNode(Node **node, int w, int h);
void print2D(Node *root, int space);
int MAX(int a, int b);
int MIN(int a, int b);


int main()
{
    Node *root;
    Block **blocks;
    int boardWidth, boardHeight, totalBlocks;
    int i, j;


    boardWidth = 500;
    boardHeight = 500;

    root = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    root->x = 0;
    root->y = 0;
    root->width = boardWidth;
    root->height = boardHeight;
    root->down = NULL;
    root->right = NULL;
    root->used = 0;

    totalBlocks = 8;
    blocks = malloc(totalBlocks * sizeof(Block));

    blocks[0] = malloc(sizeof(Block));
    blocks[0]->width = 50;
    blocks[0]->height = 50;
    blocks[0]->id = 0;
    blocks[1] = malloc(sizeof(Block));
    blocks[1]->width = 50;
    blocks[1]->height = 50;
    blocks[1]->id = 1;
    blocks[2] = malloc(sizeof(Block));
    blocks[2]->width = 102;
    blocks[2]->height = 20;
    blocks[2]->id = 2;
    blocks[3] = malloc(sizeof(Block));
    blocks[3]->width = 102;
    blocks[3]->height = 20;
    blocks[3]->id = 3;
    blocks[4] = malloc(sizeof(Block));
    blocks[4]->width = 102;
    blocks[4]->height = 20;
    blocks[4]->id = 4;
    blocks[5] = malloc(sizeof(Block));
    blocks[5]->width = 102;
    blocks[5]->height = 20;
    blocks[5]->id = 5;
    blocks[6] = malloc(sizeof(Block));
    blocks[6]->width = 102;
    blocks[6]->height = 20;
    blocks[6]->id = 6;
    blocks[7] = malloc(sizeof(Block));
    blocks[7]->width = 500;
    blocks[7]->height = 350;
    blocks[7]->id = 7;

    // Bubble Sort
    for (i = 0; i < totalBlocks; i++) {         
        for (j = 0; j < totalBlocks - i - 1; j++) {
            int maxJ = MAX(blocks[j]->height, blocks[j]->width);
            int minJ = MIN(blocks[j]->height, blocks[j]->width);

            int maxJ1 = MAX(blocks[j + 1]->height, blocks[j + 1]->width);
            int minJ1 = MIN(blocks[j + 1]->height, blocks[j + 1]->width);

            if (maxJ < maxJ1) {
                Block *b = blocks[j];
                blocks[j] = blocks[j + 1];
                blocks[j + 1] = b;
            }
            else if (maxJ == maxJ1 && minJ < minJ1) {
                Block *b = blocks[j];
                blocks[j] = blocks[j + 1];
                blocks[j + 1] = b;
            }
        }
    }
    // FIT
    for (i = 0; i < totalBlocks; i++) {
        Block *block = blocks[i];
        Node *node;
        Node * auxNode = root;
        printf("=======================================================");
        print2D(auxNode, 0);
        if (node = findNode(root, block->width, block->height)) {   
            block->fit = splitNode(&node, block->width, block->height);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < totalBlocks; i++) {
        Block *block = blocks[i];
        if (block->fit != NULL) {
            printf("x %d y %d\n", block->fit->x, block->fit->y);
            printf("w %d h %d\n", block->width, block->height);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }


    return 0;
}

Node *findNode(Node *root, int w, int h) {

    if (root->used == 1) {

        Node * rightNode = findNode(root->right, w, h);
         if (rightNode != NULL)
            return rightNode;

        Node * downNode = findNode(root->down, w, h);
        return downNode;
    }
    else if ((w <= root->width) && (h <= root->height)) {
        return root;
    }
    else {
        return NULL;
    }
}

Node *splitNode(Node **node, int w, int h) {

    (*node)->used = 1;

    (*node)->down = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    (*node)->down->parent = (*node);
    (*node)->down->down = NULL;
    (*node)->down->right = NULL;
    (*node)->down->x = (*node)->x;
    (*node)->down->y = (*node)->y + h;
    (*node)->down->width = (*node)->width;
    (*node)->down->height = (*node)->height - h;
    (*node)->down->used = 0;

    (*node)->right = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    (*node)->right->parent = (*node);
    (*node)->right->down = NULL;
    (*node)->right->right = NULL;
    (*node)->right->x = (*node)->x + w;
    (*node)->right->y = (*node)->y;
    (*node)->right->width = (*node)->width - w;
    (*node)->right->height = (*node)->height;
    (*node)->right->used = 0;

    return *node;
}

int MAX(int a, int b) {
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}
int MIN(int a, int b) {
    return (a < b) ? a : b;
}

void print2D(Node *root, int space)
{
    // Base case 
    if (root == NULL)
        return;

    // Increase distance between levels 
    space += COUNT;

    // Process right child first 
    print2D(root->right, space);

    // Print current node after space 
    // count 
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = COUNT; i < space; i++)
        printf(" ");
    printf("(w%d h%d)\n", root->width, root->height);

    // Process left child 
    print2D(root->down, space);
}
```

## The outputs of both codes:

The out put of my code will be:
 [image: my c code output]

While the out put of the javascript code with the same samples will be:
[image: js output]

**The numbers are coordinates (x, y) of each block in the top left corner (where there is a red dot). I made this for better visualization of the different outputs.

## The Error:

As you can see in the javascript output image, I draw red outlines, that is where my last 3 blocks are being place in my code, while in the javascript, its placed in the left, and **here is the error**. In my code, the blocks should also be placed in the left.
*e.g.* the last block in my code have coordinates `408, 400` while in the javascript is `50, 390`.

## My tries:

Because this is a Binary Tree, to debug it, i made a function to display it, and here is what I found out:

[image: binary tree display]

In the algorithm, it's made on purpose to always go to the `rightNode` and after, go to the `downNode`, but im my code, it's going on the `downNode` of the wrong Node. While in javascript is going everything just as intended.

## Solutions?

I'm doing this for days and what is driving me crazy is that the codes looks the same, same logic. So, if is the same logic, why it's not working?
I think that javascript high level is doing something that my C code don't do...

1. What is javascript high level doing under the hood to go in the correct node that my low level C is not doing?
2. What to do to fix this problem?

## Edit 1:

Changed

```
    Node * rightNode = findNode(root->right, w, h);
    Node * downNode = findNode(root->down, w, h);
    if (rightNode != NULL)
        return rightNode;               
    return downNode;
```

to

```
    Node * rightNode = findNode(root->right, w, h);
    if (rightNode != NULL)
        return rightNode;

    Node * downNode = findNode(root->down, w, h);
    return downNode;
```

but still have the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a bug in your code:

```
Node *findNode(Node *root, int w, int h) {

    if (root->used == 1) {
        Node * rightNode = findNode(root->right, w, h);
        Node * downNode = findNode(root->right, w, h);  //THIS LINE IS WRONG
         if (rightNode != NULL)
            return rightNode;
        return findNode(root->down, w, h);
    }
    else if ((w <= root->width) && (h <= root->height)) {
        return root;
    }
    else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

By comparison to the original JS, the line should be:

```
Node * downNode = findNode(root->down, w, h);
```

---

OK, now that the above is fixed, here is another go to fix it.

see the following code

```
Node *splitNode(Node **node, int w, int h) {

    (*node)->used = 1;

    (*node)->down = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    (*node)->down->parent = (*node);
    (*node)->down->down = NULL;
    (*node)->down->right = NULL;
    (*node)->down->x = (*node)->x;
    (*node)->down->y = (*node)->y + h;
    (*node)->down->width = (*node)->width;
    (*node)->down->height = (*node)->height - h;
    (*node)->down->used = 0;

    (*node)->right = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    (*node)->right->parent = (*node);
    (*node)->right->down = NULL;
    (*node)->right->right = NULL;
    (*node)->right->x = (*node)->x + w;
    (*node)->right->y = (*node)->y;
    (*node)->right->width = (*node)->width - w;
    (*node)->right->height = (*node)->height;   //THIS LINE
    (*node)->right->used = 0;

    return *node;
}
```

see the marked line.
This should be (I think)

```
(*node)->right->height = h;
```

(the JS has `h:h` returned not `h:node.h`)

Comment: oh sorry, I actually changed a little bit of my code to put it here and that was just a mistake, I just changed it to `Node * downNode = findNode(root->down, w, h);` and its the same.

Comment: OK, I'll keep poking to see if I can spot anything else.

Comment: One thought I had is to keep in a variable the correct parentNode to go down and when it goes down, goes to that variable, but if in js he is not doing that, why in C I would need to do that? Doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Ahhh, I thought I had something, but no.  There is a difference thought.  In the findNode function in the C you are always calculating both rightNode and downNode, whereas the JS only calculates the downNode if rightNode is null.  This shouldn't actually change the answer, however.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184524/discussion-between-euan-smith-and-vencovsky).